# how to put another piece of code inside of alert builder in android?

Tags: android

I am using alert builder for getting the confirmation from user in android but I am also need to put edittext inside of alert builder to get some data from user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom dialog :

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

https://www.udemy.com/blog/android-alertdialog-examples/

Or do some googling "android custom alert dialog"

Answer (score 0):

This is example of how you may do your task.
Places that focus on your question are marked by '-->':

```
    public void yourAlertDialog(int title, int message, int value, YourResultListener listener) {
                final View v;

                // inflate additional layout 
-->             v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edit_text, null);

                // find desired views in the inflated layout:
-->             final EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
-->             et.setText("Your text - it may be passed as parameter");

                // generate AlertDialog and return result if OK is pressed
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)//
                        .setTitle(title)//
                        .setMessage(message)//
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (listener != null) {
                                    //DO WHAT YOU NEED
                                }
                            }
                        })//
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)//
-->                     .setView(v)// adding additional view
                        .show();
    }
```

note that `this` here is your main activity

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also got the need to add EditText inside Alert Dialog, here's the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Message");
alert.setMessage("Your custom message!");

// Set an EditText view to get user input
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setText("Default text for EditText");
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

               //Get value of EditText
               String value = input.getText().toString();

              //Do whatever you want to do with EditText value
     }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
           // Canceled.
     }
});

alert.show();
```